# I cannot view the .axd page in a ELMAH project

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I am using the ELMAH project and I am unable to find the .axd page. I need to put an UpdatePanel and a timer to auto-update the page and also increase the size of the errors list on that page.

Comment: And what's the question? What error are you getting? You need a bit more info. BTW the ELMAH .axd page already auto-updates...

Comment: You need to read more about elmah, start here - http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/ErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlers.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elmah.axd 'page' does not exist as a physical file you can open and edit. It is created programatically through the compiled code.

If you want to edit the output of the error list or error details pages, you will have to go to [the source code](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/source/browse/src/Elmah/ErrorLogPage.cshtml) and manipulate it there, and then recompile your custom version.

By the way, as some comments already mention, the errors page already refreshes itself through a meta-refresh (once every 60 seconds). You can change the number of errors displayed by manipulating the query string, if need be (elmah.axd?page=1&size=100) up to a max of 100.